Identifying Mitutoyo connector
Mitutoyo is using this connector in their Digimatic dial indicators.
Is this "a standard" connector available from some connector manufacturer?
The connector is 10mm wide with five contacts.



please add the pictures directly into the question ... use the button with the mountains and sun
